# Display average response time promethues/graphana

Tags: prometheus

I would like to display the `average response time` of the requests that we receive. Currently we capture this using the `prometheus histogram` feature `duration_count`, `duration_sum`, `duration_bucket`

I'm am calculating the average using `duration_sum`/`duration_count`. But how can I represent this in graphana(what is the most suitable visualization) and what should be my y-axis.

Answer (score 0):

you can use   `rate(duration_sum[time_window])/rate(duration_count[time_window])` as the query. The type of the visualization actually depends on the data and usecase, in the simplest scenario where you only need to see the value and not its change w.r.t time you can use a stat, but if you have metrics coming in form multiple instances, and you need to see the variation w.r.t time a graph is best. You can also set thresholds to see if they meet your SLAs. Y axis should obviously be time, again it depends on the SLA, if you expect time in milliseconds range make it milli and so on.